# InitialRouteName: undefined is not an object in evaluating routeConfigs[InitialRouteName].params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Here is the working code block for `createStackNavigator({...})`, with the block for `initialRouteName` being commented out.

```
const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Event:  Event,
    Signup: Signup,
    Verif1: Verif1,
    Chat: {
      screen: ChatWithSocket,

    } 
  },  /*{
    initialRouteName: Signup,
  }  */
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(navigator);
export default AppContainer;
```

The app is running with `React Native 0.59.5` and `react navigation 3.9.1`. If the block for `initialRoutesName` is enabled (comments removed). then it popup an error:

[image]

Based on my reading online, the problem seems to be a config issue with the `React Navigation` module.

Answer (score 13):

I had to switch `initalRouteName` to `initialRouteParams`

```
const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Event:  Event,
    Signup: Signup,
    Verif1: Verif1,
    Chat: {
      screen: ChatWithSocket,

    } 
  },  {
    initialRouteParams: 'Signup',
  }  
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(navigator);
export default AppContainer;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working code. The name of initial route is a string:

```
const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Event:  Event,
    Signup: Signup,
    Verif1: Verif1,
    Chat: {
      screen: ChatWithSocket,

    } 
  },  {
    initialRouteName: 'Signup',
  }  
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(navigator);
export default AppContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

initialRouteName must be a one of the list.
As your example: it must be either Event or Signup or Verfy1 or Chat

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, when i was importing from 'react-navigation-stack' instead of "@react-navigation/stack", as written below:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
```

The problem was solved by replacing it with:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
```